# Number of picoseconds in a week is exact?

Tags: units

My [chemistry textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HR7MSE0) states that the number of picoseconds in a week is not exact because a week is defined by the Earth's rotation.

Does that also mean that 3600 seconds in an hour also isn't exact because an hour is also defined by the Earth's rotation?

Comment: The SI base unit of time is the second ($\mathrm s$). The only non-SI units of time that are generally accepted for use with the SI are the minute ($1\ \mathrm{min}=60\ \mathrm s$), the hour ($1\ \mathrm h=60\ \mathrm{min}=3600\ \mathrm s$), and the day ($1\ \mathrm d=24\ \mathrm h=86\,400\ \mathrm s$); however, that not necessarily mean that other units of time are not exact.

Comment: So in Chemistry: the hour is defined by seconds and the week is defined by the earth rotation? And the second must be defined by the rotations of an atom maybe?

Comment: A week is defined in terms of seconds. The second (nowadays) is not defined through the earth's rotation. So your book either is wrong or you might have misinterpreted it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second

Comment: @eromod The question is a good one. But it isn't a *chemistry* question which is why readers here are saying it is off topic (even if it appears in a chemistry textbook). And the real issue is that the definition of time in science is exact but that we have to adjust the length of a calendar year (sometimes by days and sometimes by seconds) to keep astronomical/calendar time in sync with precise atomic clocks because the earths rotation and orbit are not exactly in line with the clocks.

Comment: @matt Are you sure that the definition of time isnt exact in science? Thats like saying the definition of the kilogram isnt exact in science.  We start with a base and derive everything else from it right?

Comment: @eromod The definition of time is exact, its the calendar that isn't because it has to match to uneven rotation of the earth.

Comment: The calendar tries to please both the sun and the digital measurements. Thats why we have leap days and leap seconds. So even if you base your measurements on the official calendar, you would still get a specific amount of picoseconds, though the amount of picoseconds per day may be different so its not as useful to use the calendar for such a precise measurement. Better to use something digital, like a satellites do when they need very precise measurements of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where if you need high levels of precision then you need to be clear about your definitions.

- A week is 7 days

but what is a day?

The SI talks about the units of "minute", "hour" and "day" in ["Non-SI units accepted for use with the International System of Units"](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/table6.html). It defines them as 60s, 3600s and 86400s. This is a definition and so it is by it's nature an exact number.

But this is only one definition. A day can also be defined as the time taken for the earth to rotate so the same place is facing the sun (a solar day) or the time taken for the "time of day" on clocks to come back to the same value.

The length of a solar day varies cyclicly by nearly 30 seconds over the course of a year due to the shape of the Earth's orbit. The average over longer periods also varies slighly.

A day of UTC is normally 86400 seconds as measured by averaging a load of atomic clocks but occasionally a UTC day may by 86401 or 86399 seconds due to leap seconds.

A day of local civil time is also normally 86400 seconds but daylight savings time shifts may lead to a day as short as 82800 seconds or as long as 93600 seconds.

Comment: So if this question appears on a multiple choice test (like mine did) what would you answer? Number of pico seconds in a week is exact or not?

Comment: Im guessing you would answer no because a week isnt an accepted SI standard unit? But  the amount of people in a classroom is an exact amount, even though "number of people" isnt an accepted SI unit either.

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of those crappy questions where the only way to ensure a "correct" answer is to know what the test-setter is expecting.

Comment: I think they are expecting a correct answer, no?

Comment: @eromod "Correct" depends on the assumptions that have been made in the course of construction the question. Different premises can lead to different "correct" answers.

Comment: @hBy, that makes sense, but as Peter pointed out, the International System of Units website shows that time isnt based on the sun anymore. Its based on specific and exact ratios like 1 min = 60s. So the default assumption should be that the amount of pico seconds in a week is indeed exact. Just like how there is 1,000 mm in a meter.

Comment: @eromod I reject your implicit premise that ***all*** time units in use today are SI units, or directly derivable therefrom; I further reject your explicit premise that all measures of time are no longer based on the sun.

Comment: Where would you draw the line? At pico seconds, at seconds at hours, at days, at weeks, at months, at seasons? Wouldint it be more consistent to choose just one? This is sort of like saying: I accept that a meter has 1000mm but I dont accept that a light year has x amount of meters in it.

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem in the statement of the question because you are asking for a simple answer. There is no simple answer:

Time is defined so that the laws of science look simple. You can define it any way you like, but it's most useful when computation and expressing quantitative relationships are easy.

A week is not a unit that a chemist generally needs to deal with, unless they are meeting a grant deadline that is due in a week. Frankly, the same is true for physicists, but it is the time keepers who decide on minute adjustments of leap seconds who need to account for the discrepancies.

No measurement is perfectly precise, so time measurements are not perfectly precise. Even the hyperfine transitions of a cesium atom that we use to define a second have some variability.

Here's the nail in the coffin. Is time even measurable? The Einsteinian Equivalent Principle says that gravitation is like an acceleration so the very act of living on Earth means that our time measurements are dilated with respect to an observer who is far away from massive bodies (whatever that means). Technically, a week is a different number of seconds for someone on the top of Everest versus someone at the bottom of the Marina Trench.

My key point here is that measurement and all of its complications is part of the crux of science, and it makes science what it is. You're asking the right kinds of questions, but don't expect simple answers.

Comment: [Archived discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51119/discussion-between-zhe-and-eromod).